# Make: syntax error near unexpected token `--initialization'

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write 'if' check in define directive in one of our make file.
Actually I am trying to check platform and proceed with environment setting.

```
define templ_32
mkdir -p $(@D)
if [ "$(PLAT)" = "x86_64" ]; then env PERLLIB=$(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 --template $<; fi
if [ "$(PLAT)" = "aarch64" ]; then env PERLLIB=$(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 --template $<; fi 
endef
```

I am using above define directive in one of my target recipe as follows.

```
some/%.c: test/tmpl-%.c $(NEW_DATA32)
    $(templ_32) --initialization $(NEW_DATA32)
```

When I run the build with above changes. I am getting error :

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `--initialization'
```

And also from the log I am seeing whole 'if' condition as follows.

```
if [ "aarch64" = "x86_64" ]; then env PERLLIB=$(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 --template /test/deploy/tmpl-kt.c ; fi --initialization /work/deploy/test.pl
```

From my success log which has no conational 'if' statements I can see only

```
env PERLLIB=$(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 --template /test/deploy/tmpl-kt.c --initialization /work/deploy/test.pl
```

I don't want to get the 'if' checks along with 'env' command.. I am only interested in

```
env PERLLIB=$(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 --template
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use make conditionals instead of shell `if` statements:

```
ifeq ($(PLAT),x86_64)
PERLVERSION = 5.10.0
else ifeq ($(PLAT),aarch64)
PERLVERSION = 5.8.0
else
$(error "Unknown arhictecture: $(PLAT)")
endif
```

And then:

```
PERLLIB = $(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/$(PERLVERSION)

some/%.c: test/tmpl-%.c $(NEW_DATA32)
    mkdir -p $(@D); \
    env PERLLIB=$(PERLLIB) --template $< --initialization $(NEW_DATA32)
```

Comment: Tq.. It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use constructed macro names for this.  For example:

```
PLATFORMS := x86_64 aarch64

$(or $(filter $(PLAT),$(PLATFORMS)),$(error Unknown architecture: $(PLAT)))

x86_64_PERLVER := 5.10.0
aarch64_PERLVER := 5.8.0

PERLLIB = $(EXTLIBS)/$(PLAT32)/lib/perl5/site_perl/$($(PLAT)_PERLVER)
```

More on this [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/).